# How to reuse Startup.cs in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a couple of similar projects. And I want to reuse `Startup.cs` file among them.

I have created a base class library called `BaseWeb` and inside it I have created a centralized `Startup.cs` class.

Now when I use this class in my project, I get **404** for every URL:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                //webBuilder.UserStartup<Startup>(); => replaced this Startup.cs
                webBuilder.UseStartup<BaseWeb.Startup>();
            });
}
```

What should I do? How can I reuse `Startup.cs` across projects?

Comment: It is better to keep each project startup file separate. For the common settings (registration, middleware settings, etc.), create extension methods for `IServiceCollection` and `IApplicationBuilder`, put them in a shared class library project, then just call them from each startup.

Comment: @LazZiya, all of these applications are part of a SPL (software product line), thus all of their structures are 100% similar. Thus it makes sense to centralize similar parts.

Comment: Hi @webdesigner, can you share the Startup.cs content? For the Razor page application, we should enable the RazorPages service in the Startup.cs: `services.AddRazorPages();` and `endpoints.MapRazorPages();`. If still not working, check the [razor page route configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [Use hosting startup assemblies in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: I just moved some parts of the Configure method to static methods in a static Startup class in the common assembly. So it is still possible to register specific middlewares but the common code is no more duplicated.